# Can not retrieve parameters

Tags: ros, moveit, getparam, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running `ur5_moveit_config demo.launch` from ros-industrial's `universal robot` package and I'd like to control it from my node. For that purpose I need to retrieve several parameters from parameter server. The first one is `planning_plugin`.

Calling `rosparam list | grep planning_plugin` gives `/move_group/planning_plugin`. Which means that parameter exists.

Here is my node initialization code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_loader.h>

/* Moveit includes */
#include <moveit/robot_model/robot_model.h>
#include <moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h>
#include <moveit/planning_interface/planning_interface.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/DisplayTrajectory.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/PlanningScene.h>
#include <moveit/kinematic_constraints/utils.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "arm_control_node");
    ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
    spinner.start();
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle("/move_group/arm_control");
    
    std::string planner_plugin_name; //= "ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner";
    
    if (!node_handle.getParam("planning_plugin", planner_plugin_name)) {
        ROS_FATAL_STREAM("Could not find planner plugin name");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Launching executable with `rosrun arm_control arm_control_node` prints `[FATAL] [1508419005.957461571]: Could not find planner plugin name`. However `rosparam get /move_group/planning_plugin` outputs `ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner`.

I have tried to hardcode plugin name as a result I have got an error about retrieving other parameters. It seems like the node can not get access to them but why is a mystery for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273527/can-not-retrieve-parameters./) by [Long Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/28619/long-smith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:\

> I'd like to control it from my node

looking at your `#include`s: are you planning to load planning plugins directly? That is possible, but just wanted to make sure you are aware there is a ROS API (ie: services and actions) available that is probably much easier to use.

**Comment by [Long Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/28619/long-smith/) on 2017-10-19**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks again! Gonna take a look. It is just a part of the `motion_planning_api_tutorial` from moveit page. Wonder why do they use direct plugin loading if there are easier methods to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ros::NodeHandle node_handle("/move_group/arm_control");
> ```

```
...
node_handle.getParam("planning_plugin", ...);
```

and:

> Launching executable with `rosrun arm_control arm_control_node` prints `[FATAL] [1508419005.957461571]: Could not find planner plugin name`. However `rosparam get /move_group/planning_plugin` outputs `ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner`.

Parameter lookups are relative to the `ros::NodeHandle` that you do them with.

In this case you ask for `planning_plugin` with a `NodeHandle` that you created in the `/move_group/arm_control` namespace. So in the end, `node_handle` will try to retrieve `/move_group/arm_control/planning_plugin` for you.

That parameter doesn't exist, hence the error.

---

Do you have a specific reason for creating your main `ros::NodeHandle` in that namespace?

It is perfectly ok to create `NodeHandle`s in namespaces like that, but especially the "first one" is typically created without any namespace declaration at all.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Long Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/28619/long-smith/) on 2017-10-19**:
Yeah, I've read about it. Actually that was just one of the many attempts to make it work but the first one used global resolution `node_handle.getParam("/move_group/planning_plugin", ...)` and it failed for some reason(wonder if it was a type since I checked spelling).

**Comment by [Long Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/28619/long-smith/) on 2017-10-19**:
Whatsoever  it was, now, thanks to your answer, it works.